# Can't find a way to select specific elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select theses elements with JQuery :

```
<div attribute="distinct-value"> <!-- i only want links in this one, select based on the attribute -->
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="col1">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- i want this -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- col3, col4, etc, etc... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div attribute="another-distinct-value">
<!-- same content structure has 'distinct-value div' -->
</div>
<div attribute="another-other-distinct-value">
<!-- same content structure has 'distinct-value div' -->
</div>
```

I want the first link in the first li of every ul markups that are not inside a li, for every div that has a "col" class. I hope everything is clear..

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your elements like so

```
$('div[attribute="distinct-value"] [class^=col] li:has(ul) > a').each(function(index) {
   console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
  });
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But i forgot something, plz check the edit of my post

Comment: @devz see edit for change. I've added div[attribute] into selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div[class^=col] > ul > li > a').each(function() {
    doSomething( $(this) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target li that has ul in it along with immediate child selector(`>`) to target immediate child anchor element:

```
 $('[class^=col] li:has(ul) > a');
```

You can iterate over above set of elements and perform the task. If you want to get all the hrefs of anchor element, you need to use `.map()` with `.get()`:

```
 var allhref =  $('[class^=col] li:has(ul) > a').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href');
 }).get();
```

```js
var allhref =  $('[class^=col] li:has(ul) > a').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href');
 }).get();
alert(allhref);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div attribute="distinct-value">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="col1">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- i want this -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- col3, col4, etc, etc... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well !! great answer but he also want to select only those div's which have for every div that has a "col" class.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But i forgot something, plz check the edit of my post

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('div[class^=col] > ul > li > a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div attribute="distinct-value">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="col1">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link" id="1"></a> <!-- i want this -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link" id="2"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link" id="3"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link" id="4"></a> <!-- and this... -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="useless_link"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- col3, col4, etc, etc... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```